# Saving user in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

In sails.js 0.9.7, how can I debug model.create() if done() function never called ?

I have a form like that;

```
<form action="/user/create" method="post">
```

And in my UserController;

```
create: function (req, res, next) {

    User.create(req.params.all()).done(function (err, user) {
        if ( err ) {
            return next(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(user);
        }
    });
},
```

Also; I check req.params and as it supposed to be but done() function never called and POST request hanging in client side.

Comment: I've duplicated your code in a project that can be found here:https://github.com/irlnathan/sails-createExample-stackoverflow-Question and it works, there must be something else going on.  Are you using the default sails-disk or another adapter?

Comment: Yes, I'm using default sails-disk. I've cloned and it works fine. I guess I will start from stracth. Also; I created a [repo](http://github.com/ubaltaci/sailsjs-register-test); you can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User model, you need to use the next() method. This method passes control back to the next piece of middleware on the stack.  Without it, it blocks execution.

```
// Lifecycle Callbacks
beforeCreate: function(values, next) {
  next();
},
```